# can I override sass variables after they have been imported?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using bootstrap-sass in my rails app. I want to override a bootstrap-sass variable $navbarBackground. bootstrap-sass also defines variables for colors. So instead of using the hex code I would like to use the variable $red that it defines.

```
$navbarBackground: #9d261d;
@import "bootstrap";
```

However if I do the following -

```
$navbarBackground: $red;
@import "bootstrap";
```

It will give me an error as the variable $red is only defined the bootstrap file which is imported in the next line.

So is there a way I can override sass variables after they have been imported ?

EDIT

I have pushed the project on github - https://github.com/murtaza52/rails-base

And the url is accessible on localhost:3000/posts/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a what I realized. You can override sass variables after they have been imported. But the modification will be reflected only in the usage after overriding. Since `navbar` got styles before you overrode the `$navbarBackground`, just overriding the variable won't change styling. See below example.

```
@import "bootstrap";
@navbarBackground: $red;
// This doesn't work. Navbar will still be same color.
// But if you do write styles for navbar again
.navbar-inner { background: $navbarBackground; }
// Now, Navbar will have a red background

@import "bootstrap";
$blue: $white;
// After this line, whenever your reference $blue, it'll generate white color.
```

Comment: Thanks Kulbir, that did the trick ! However when I look at the _bootstrap.scss by opening up the gem, I see that it starts with the following line `// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
@import "bootstrap/mixins";` Is it possible for me to just import the variables first and modify them, and then import the whole bootstrap ?

Comment: If you import `bootstrap/variables`, modify variables and then import `bootstrap`, I guess, the variables will again be overridden. Because, bootstrap will again import `bootstrap/variables`. It's worth a try though.

Comment: Won't your output css be double the file size now as you are importing bootstrap twice?

Comment: You're using a less variable in your first `@navbarBackground` declaration - should be `$navbarBackground`

Comment: "You can override variables by simply redefining the variable before the @import directive." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435612/overriding-bootstrap-variables-in-rails-with-bootstrap-sass-gem

Answer (score 23):

Bootstrap-sass is defining many variables in [/bootstrap/_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) in the style `$brand-success: #5cb85c !default;`. The sass keyword `!default` means:

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding the !default flag to the end of the value. This means that if the variable has already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but if it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one.
>   ([→sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_))

This means you just have to define your variables *first*, before importing bootstrap-sass. I do it like so:

```
@import "common/project_variables";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Where my file `project_variables.scss` contains – among others – exactly all bootstrap variables I want to override.

Comment: The order of imports is exactly the reverse if you are using bootstrap less variables. In case of less, you will `@import ''bootstrap";` before `@import "common/project_variables";`

Comment: thanks this fixed everything, import variables *before* bootstrap. Never knew what `!default` did, awesome answer!

Answer (score 17):

I'm doing it by importing individual scss files to my application.scss file. Instead of writing this:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I first import variables, customize them, and only then import rest of the bootstrap.

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";

$body-bg: #333333;

@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/normalize";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/print";

// Core CSS
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/scaffolding";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/type";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/code";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/grid";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/tables";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/forms";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/buttons";

// Components
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/component-animations";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/glyphicons";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/dropdowns";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/button-groups";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/input-groups";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/navs";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/navbar";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/breadcrumbs";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/pagination";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/pager";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/labels";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/badges";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/jumbotron";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/thumbnails";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/alerts";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/progress-bars";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/media";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/list-group";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/panels";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/wells";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/close";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/modals";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/tooltip";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/popovers";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/carousel";

// Utility classes
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/utilities";
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/responsive-utilities";


body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap variables use the `!default` rule.

**Default rule:**

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding the !default flag to the end of the value. This means that if the variable has already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but if it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one.

This is what it looks like:

```
$example: 'value' !default;
```

So using Sass `!default` is like adding an “unless this is already assigned” qualifier to your variable assignments