# Overriding Bootstrap variables in Rails with bootstrap-sass gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the `bootstrap-sass` gem (Bootstrap 3.0) by Thomas McDonald.  I've followed the 
[Bootstrap and Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-rails.html) tutorial by Daniel Kehoe.

I have `application.css.scss` which has the following at the top:

```
 /*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

And I have `framework_and_overrides.css.scss` which has this line in it:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Now I tried overriding bootstrap variables (`$body-bg: #f00;`) I found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables) and placing them in either of these two files but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can override variables by simply redefining the variable *before* the `@import` directive.

For example:

```
$navbar-default-bg: #312312;
$light-orange: #ff8c00;
$navbar-default-color: $light-orange;

@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: That works, except when I try to use bootstrap variables before the `@import "bootstrap"` directive I get an undefined variable error.  i.e. `$text-color: $gray-light;`

Comment: You can't use gray-light var, because it isn't defined.

Comment: But why doesn't it work if I redefine them after the `@import`? Shouldn't sass simply take the last variable definition as other languages do?

Comment: In Sass variables need to be defined before they can be used - in this case if you want to redefine a variable it needs to be done before the `@import` directive so the Bootstrap scss files can make use of it. The only reason they don't get overwritten by the default values is because [the default values all use the `!default` flag](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss), meaning they'll only use that value if the variable hasn't already been defined.

Comment: Just wanted to add also that if you were using Less it would be different because it uses the notion of [variable scope](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope) (whereas in Sass all variables are global), and that allows you to redefine variables _after_ the `@import` because they get loaded before any inner scopes, and these ones do simply overwrite the default values (no need for `!default`).

Comment: This is a particular case.. this works because Bootstrap variables haves the `!default` qualifier.. if you try to do this with another variable that doesn't have `!default` it will be overriden again by the latest definition

Comment: This is not working for me. `@import variables`, then `@import bootstrap` in `application.sass`. For example: `$link-color: #FF0000` is ignored, as well as any other boostrap override.

Answer (score 1):

see the execution cycle. in the bootstrap file, files rendering in this manner such us "get variable > and apply in navbar" this really happen when started to execute the bootstrap file. Its present inside of the bootstrap, look the sequential flow of importing . , the variable are getting from bootstrap/variables and setting up the vavbar color in bootstrap/navbar, this applying the color in navbar with the variable `navbar-default-bg`.

what actually programmers are doing is trying to setup the variable value after setting up the color in navbar. **(before or after "@importing bootstrap" statement,the variable changes  will not make changes in the navbar color, need to edit in the bootstrap file)**

look into the code below if you want to change the color you have to do the following.

> ### inside bootstrap file
>
> // Core variables and mixins
>
> @import "bootstrap/variables";
>
> // Components
>
> @import "bootstrap/navs";
>
> $navbar-default-bg:red; **// initialize the *$navbar-default-bg* (after importing bootstrap/variables)**
>
> @import "bootstrap/navbar"; here the color setting is performing"

this will work fine, analyze the execution cycle.

but I am suggesting use the other manual classes for applying the bg-color instead of over riding bootstrap variable.

Ref : https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap/issues/12