# Accessing file within bootstrap-sass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Rails project, and I need to customize a couple variables in Twitter Bootstrap's CSS to disable responsive features that end up looking weird.

To do so, I know I need to enter the `bootstrap-sass` folder to access the variables file, so, from the command line, I run:

```
 $cd `bundle show bootstrap-sass`
```

Then I run:

```
 $find vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

So far so good. I see a listing of all of the stylesheets in /assets, which includes the `vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss` that I want to get into.

I try to run a `$open vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss`, but it returns an error:

```
 No application knows how to open /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss.
```

Any ideas on how I can open and edit this file?

Comment: If you are trying to edit the file, could you try 

`$pico vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss` or 

`$cat vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss` or just

`vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, you don't ever want to overwrite hard-coded (default) variables; you want to [over**ride**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20435683/1143732) them:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass
@import custom_vars #-> your own variables file
@import bootstrap

#app/assets/stylehseets/custom_vars.sass
$override_1: "x"
```

> In Sass variables need to be defined before they can be used - in this case if you want to redefine a variable it needs to be done before the `@import` directive so the Bootstrap scss files can make use of it.

Just declare the custom variables *before* you call `@import bootstrap` and it will use your values over the hard-coded ones.

---

This is co-oberated with the fact that the [vars in `bootstrap`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) are declared with the [`!default`](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-default) switch -- meaning [they're *meant* to be overridden](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_):

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding the `!default` flag to the end of the value. This means that if the variable has already been assigned, it won’t be re-assigned, but if it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one