# sass: overwrite one var with another

Tags: variables, sass, overriding, redefine

We've got our sass variables file set up like

`scss\variables\_custom_variables.scss`.

Which, of course contains things like

`$link-color: $00f;`

Then put to use in our sass files set up like this one for navigation as `scss\main\_main_nav.scss` where we have rules like

`a {color: $link-color;}`

Now we've got a new feature allowing for custom styling, which pulls in the variables as well as everything in `scss\main\`. In lieu of creating something like

`scss\main_2\_main_nav.scss` ad infinitum

I'd like to be able to redefine `$link-color`.

I was hoping I could simply create `scss\new_file\_variables.scss` and have a list of overrides like

`$link-color: #36c;`

but this is not working as expected. What could I be doing better?

Thanks, all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I override sass variables after they have been imported?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773583/can-i-override-sass-variables-after-they-have-been-imported)

Comment: I don't think so:

In a global, I'm setting my variables, and i am using `!default` at that point. However, we're going to start creating different color schemes and I'd like to just re-define those vars in lieu of new rules.:

`global.scss: $primary-color: red !default;` and then 

`custom.scss: $primary-color: blue;`

despite respecting the stack order, keeps compiling:
`$primary-color: red;`

Answer (score 0):

You can define your base-variables with the default-flag: `$var1: lightblue !default;`

and override them in the theme using `$var1: red;`

If you `@import` the variable-files in the right order, `red` overrides `lightblue`.

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-variable-scope-in-sass--cms-23498

Comment: Great link. Thanks. Going to look in to scope being an issue.